# Are my sort algorithms correct? Why does merge sort take fewer iterations than quick sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have been experimenting with the number of iterations of various sorting algorithms. I have been trying to figure out which ones take most iterations to execute. I define an iteration as either a iteration through a loop or the execution of a function (In order to take recursion into account). Quick Sort and Merge sort seem to be a lot faster than Bubble Sort as far as performance. Quick sort seems to be faster in cases where there are fewer items in the array. This could be because my quick Sort algorithm is not very efficient.

My question is Quick Sort take fewer iterations than Merge Sort and if so why. I have also listed my code below in case my algorithms are incorrect. Thank you.

```
function quickSort(arr){
        iter++;
        let length = arr.length;
        let pivot_index =  [length-1]; //Math.floor(Math.random() * [length -1]);
    let index = 0;
    while(pivot_index>index){
        iter++;
        if(arr[pivot_index]<arr[index]){
            let temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[pivot_index-1];
            arr[pivot_index-1] = arr[pivot_index] ;
            arr[pivot_index] = temp;
            --pivot_index
        }
        else
            ++index;
    }

    if(length>3)
        return  quickSort(arr.slice(0, pivot_index)).concat([arr[pivot_index]],quickSort(arr.slice(pivot_index+1)));
    else
        return arr;
}



function selectionSort(arr){
    let numIterations = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        numIterations+=1;
        for(let j = i +1; j<arr.length; j++){
            if( arr[i] > arr[j]){
                let temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            numIterations+=1;
        }
    }
    return {"num_iterations": numIterations, "arr":arr}

}


function bubbleSort(arr){

    let numIterations = 0;
    let count = 0;
    do{
        var swapped = false;
        numIterations+=1;
        count+=1;
        for(let i = 0;i<arr.length-count;i++){
            numIterations+=1;
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                let temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }

    } while(swapped == true)
    return {"num_iterations": numIterations, "arr":arr}
}

function mergeSort(arr){
    iter+=1;

    if(arr.length>1){
        let divsor = arr.length + 1;
        let arr_left_half = arr.slice(0,parseInt(divsor / 2));
        let arr_right_half = arr.slice(parseInt( divsor / 2));
        arr = null;
        var tup_arr = [mergeSort(arr_left_half), mergeSort(arr_right_half)];

    }else
        return arr;

    let l = []

    while(tup_arr[0].length > 0 || tup_arr[1].length > 0){
        iter+=1;
        let arr1_length = tup_arr[0].length;
        let arr2_length = tup_arr[1].length;
        if(arr1_length > 0 && arr2_length > 0){
            if(tup_arr[0][0] > tup_arr[1][0])
                l.push(tup_arr[1].shift());
            else
                l.push(tup_arr[0].shift());
        }
        else if( arr1_length > 0)
            l.push(tup_arr[0].shift());
        else if(arr2_length > 0)
            l.push(tup_arr[1].shift())

    }
    tup_arr = null;
    return l;

}

let iter = 0;
let arr = []
for(let i =0;i<10000;i++){
   let num =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
   arr.push(num);
}

let bubble_sort = bubbleSort(arr.slice());
let selection_sort = selectionSort(arr.slice());
let merge_sort = mergeSort(arr.slice());
console.log("Merge Sort Iterations:"+iter);
iter = 0;
let quick_sort = quickSort(arr.slice());
console.log("Quick Sort Iterations:"+iter);
console.log("Selection Sort Iterations:"+selection_sort.num_iterations);
console.log("Bubble Sort Iterations:"+bubble_sort.num_iterations);
```

Comment: *better* is quite a broad term...

Comment: In terms of memory consumption in implementations that intelligently choose a pivot, yes quick sort consumes far less memory. However, there is no array where merge sort is not optimal, while there are arrays that make quick sort less than optimal, so that's a trade off.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Tahnk you for the answer I appreciate it.

Comment: By the way, if you want a reference implementation to compare yours to, you can check out my [sort-viz repository](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz) on github. I implemented them as an override of the `sort()` member method on extension classes of `Array`. Here's [merge sort](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz/blob/master/lib/comparative/merge/recursive.js) (and its [`merge()` method](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz/blob/master/lib/comparative/merge.js)) and [quick sort](https://github.com/patrickroberts/sort-viz/blob/master/lib/comparative/quick.js).

Comment: @Patrick Thanks I will take a look at it!

Comment: This question seems more suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Actually mergesort is not the best known for having few comparisons.  Ford-Johnson beats it, though it is never used in practice because it has too much overhead.  See http://www.mat.unb.br/~ayala/4FordJohnson.pdf for a description.  And Ford-Johnson is known not to be optimal, though we have no candidates that are consistently better.

Comment: @btilly My understanding is that one of the commonly used generic sorting methods in production code or built-ins is TimSort, though in cases where a non-comparative sort can be used, some variation of Radix sort is preferred.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts TimSort is used because it can take advantage of realistic runs of "partially sorted data".  Across random arrays, though, it is slightly worse than MergeSort.  Radix sort is better where feasible because it is `O(n)` rather than `O(n log(n))`.  Quicksort has the benefit of little memory overhead and and simple implementation.  Ford-Johnson has a better worst case number of comparisons, but way too much bookkeeping overhead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mergesort always recurses to depth `⌈log2N⌉`. At every recursion level every element is compared once.

Quicksort can only achieve that if it guesses the optimal partition value every time, which is not very likely. Generally, one side of the partition will be larger than the other side. Balancing that increased recursion depth a bit is the fact that once a partition is sorted, its elements are no longer compared. So some elements are compared more and others less. Under one plausible definition of "average case", quicksort is expected to do about 40% more comparisons than mergesort.

But quicksort has a big advantage for large datasets. In mergesort, the merge step cannot be done efficiently in place. The algorithm depends on being able to use temporary storage of the same size as the original dataset.

So mergesort is probably better if you have enough storage available. At least that was the judgement of the authors of glibc, whose `qsort` implementation does a mergesort unless the dataset is quite large.

Comment: Iterative (bottom up) merge sort doesn't use any recursion, just iterative passes. It's a bit faster since it doesn't have do any stack operations. On a system with 16 registers and an 8 way associative cache, a 4-way merge sort is a bit faster then a 2-way merge sort. As already commented above, hybrid sorts like timsort are faster still.